# Python Script suddenly crashes

Tags: python, while-loop

I created a program that follows the prices of the stocks market, I put a script that tests the server each time if there are error messages or not, it works very well but sometimes when the script receives an error message it prints what I want to print but the whole script crashes afterwards, even Ctrl C no longer works and I would have to close the whole terminal. No error message displayed, Nothing !
Everything is blocked, I have not found a solution.

```
while True : 
    try :
        get_price ='Website link here'
        print('Current Price Here')
        break
    except(requests.exceptions.ConnectionError) :
        print("No live Price Now ! ")
        continue
```

Comment: My guess would be that the script is receiving a separate error from the one you explicitly catch.

Comment: You don't need `continue`. Loops continue automatically unless you break out or the while condition is false.

Comment: The code you posted most definitely doesn't crash. Please try to provide a [mcve] or maybe post the relevant part of your _actual_ code